# Sticky sessions with Apache load balancer for Socket.io 1.0

Tags: load-balancing, apache-2.4, node.js, sticky-sessions, websocket

I've been messing around with Apache as a load balancer for my Socket.io server. I went through the following topic and now everything seems to be fine.

[Configuring Apache 2.4 mod_proxy_wstunnel for Socket.IO 1.0](https://serverfault.com/questions/616370/configuring-apache-2-4-mod-proxy-wstunnel-for-socket-io-1-0/623027#623027?newreg=acc6498f20a1425aa45e6052cf5514ae)

I configured Apache using the following config and now the connections are being upgraded to WebSocket. But when I try to enable sticky sessions for the following config, it seems like sometimes apache routes the upgrade request to route #2 while the polling was established on route #1. When this happens, upgrade fails and websocket is not connected. Since we have to balancers (one for http and one for ws), I thought maybe the cookie set by http route #1 , cannot be accessed by ws routes and that's why sessions are not sticky among http and ws.

I'm using apache 2.4.9

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED

    ProxyRequests off

    ServerName localhost

    <Proxy balancer://http-localhost/>
        BalancerMember http://localhost:8081 route=1 keepalive=On smax=1 connectiontimeout=10 retry=600 timeout=900 ttl=900
        BalancerMember http://localhost:8082 route=2 keepalive=On smax=1 connectiontimeout=10 retry=600 timeout=900 ttl=900

        ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
        ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
    </Proxy>

    <Proxy balancer://ws-localhost/>
        BalancerMember ws://localhost:8081 route=1 keepalive=On smax=1 connectiontimeout=10 retry=600 timeout=900 ttl=900
        BalancerMember ws://localhost:8082 route=2 keepalive=On smax=1 connectiontimeout=10 retry=600 timeout=900 ttl=900

        ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
        ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
    </Proxy>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io                [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket        [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)           balancer://ws-localhost/$1 [P,L]

    ProxyPass /socket.io balancer://http-localhost/socket.io
    ProxyPassReverse /socket.io balancer://http-localhost/socket.io
</VirtualHost>
```